# Populate linked entities tree from Microsoft Dynamics crm

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

Is there any tool or option in Dynamics CRM to see all linked entities tree deeply, like at least 4 levels?

No need to programmatically display them, just for seeing a structure, because there are so many inherited lookups, but I need find some specific values, knowing the names, will know, where to find. Clicking step by step all of them, will consume lot of time.

Comment: What version of CRM? What entity?

Comment: CRM 2016 Service Pack 1 (8.1.0.359) . entity name: cds_client

Comment: Thanks. Does the entity have a self-referential hierarchical relationship? And are the hierarchy settings configured? Once you have it set right, in a view of that entity you should see an icon next to records that are part of a hierarchy. Clicking that icon will display the tree view.

Comment: unfortunately no, there is no hierarchical settings set to entity. And no, it is not reference to it self. Does this hierarchical settings I need to configure only for top entity, or for linked too? and how it changes functionality of CRM or is it only informational view?

Comment: As far as I know, hierarchy can only be configured for a single entity (though this may have changed since I last checked.) The classic example is the Account entity, which has hierarchy enabled by default. What enables hierarchy is a "self-referential" 1:N relationship on the entity - i.e. an account can have multiple child accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have used Network visualization from SparkleXRM for similar scenario. This support custom entity as well. Brilliant stuff!

Just need to install couple of managed solution & minor config settings if needed. It ll suffice your need.

https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crmcat/archive/2016/10/08/sparkle-xrm-network-visualization-deep-dive

Comment: yes, this looks, what I need. Week is over and this will be my Mondays morning new toy. Thanks.